# Jenkins doesn't seem to be cloning GitHub repo -- no files found on npm install

Tags: node.js, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins setup is successfully triggering on `push` from the GitHub. It runs this `Jenkinsfile`:

```
node {
  sh 'npm install'
}
```

Which spits out this error:

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME\package.json'

Looking at that folder, there are no contents. While I assumed that the cloned repository would've been there.

In the configuration within Jenkins, the Branch Source is set up and is using the credentials.

Am I missing a step? Do I have to explicitly tell it to clone within the `Jenkinsfile`?

Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you'll need to checkout the repository.

```
#!groovy
node {
    stage "Checkout Repo"
    checkout scm

    stage "Install Dependencies"
    sh 'npm install'
}
```